# Reference request for $e^{t A}\otimes e^{sB} = e^{tA\otimes I + sI\otimes B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $A$ and $B$ be two bounded linear operators on $\mathscr{H}$. I'm looking for references (preferably books) which state and prove the following identity:
$$e^{tA}\otimes e^{s B} = e^{t A\otimes I + s I\otimes B}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a reference, but the proof is fairly straightforward. We note that whenever operators $P,Q$ over $\mathscr H$ commute (i.e. $PQ = QP$), we have $e^{P + Q} = e^Pe^Q$. Noting that $t A \otimes I$ commutes with $s I \otimes B$, we find that
$$
e^{t A \otimes I + s I \otimes B} = e^{t A \otimes I} e^{s I \otimes B}.
$$
On the other hand, we note that
$$
e^{tA \otimes I} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(tA \otimes I)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} A^k \otimes I = 
\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} A^k \right) \otimes I = e^{t A} \otimes I.
$$
Using a similar derivation, conclude that $e^{s I \otimes B} = I \otimes e^{s B}$. Finally, we can use the fact that $[A \otimes B][C \otimes D] = [AC]\otimes [BD]$ to conclude that
$$
e^{t A \otimes I + s I \otimes B} = e^{t A \otimes I} e^{s I \otimes B}
= ([e^{tA}] \otimes I)(I \otimes [e^{sB}]) = e^{tA} \otimes e^{sB}.
$$

Comment: Wow! That's a nice answer!